# PSPICE. Error 15053: Unable to initialize PSpice UI

Tags: pspice

I have a problem every time I try to simulate in PSpice.
When I click Run it appears the following window:

> ERROR(15053):Unable to initialize PSpice UI

Can someone please help me with this? I need to use PSpice for a subject in my university.
I would really appreciate any information that anyone could give me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.orcad.com/documents/community.faqs/pspice/020818.aspx)?

Comment: I have seen the link you attached. The problem is that I have the Orcad Pspice 16.6 version installed in Parallels Desktop with windows XP (As I have a mac laptop and there isn't a version of Pspice for mac)

Comment: I have seen the link you attached. The problem is that I have the Orcad Pspice 16.6 version installed in Parallels Desktop with windows XP (As I have a mac laptop and there isn't a version of Pspice for mac). The problem appears in the step 4, when I try to move the acceleration slider bar, because this does not appear; more over, I think that I don't have an ATI Mobility AGP 128 Graphics Adapter as I am using Parallels Desktop. Do you know anything else that I may do? or another way of decreasing the bar? Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

- I resolved this error by replacing the file in

> pspice.ini

- In path **C:\SPB_Data\cdssetup\OrCAD_PSpice\16.6.0** from the cadence installed folder.
- Restart the Orcad PSpice program and try to run the simulation.